# Configure proxy setting for client node app accesses Azure ServiceBus with Azure SDK for Node

Tags: node.js, azure, proxy, servicebus

I used the Azure SDK for node to create a client app to send and receive data to an Azure Service Bus Topics. The app runs fine with direct connection from my device to Azure cloud.  For enterprise environment, the device and client app must be run behind a firewall.

```
  +---------+        +------------+         +-------------------+
  | Device  |   <=>  | HTTP Proxy |   <=>   | Azure SB endpoint |
  +---------+        +------------+         +-------------------+
```

The Azure SDK ServiceClient code shows that it would automatically use the proxy setting from the environment variable -

```
 HTTPS_PROXY=http://<proxy-server>:<proxy port>.
```

I set the environment variable as such and it did not work. The connection failed on the SDK calls with:

```
Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=socket hang up
```

I used the 'azure-sdk-for-node\examples\samples\sbtopics.js' to test with proxy, it failed the same way.

I tried to modify the default proxy and it did not fix the problem. 
...

```
var serviceBusClient = azure.createServiceBusService(azureSBSASStr);
var defaultProxy = serviceBusClient.proxy;  // get the default proxy
var auth = 'Basic ' + new Buffer('username:password').toString('base64');

// override default
defaultProxy.auth = auth;
defaultProxy.rejectUnauthorized = false;
defaultProxy.secureOptions = constants.SSL_OP_NO_TLSv1_2;  // also used SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3
defaultProxy.strictSSL = false;

// set the proxy
serviceBusClient.setProxy(defaultProxy);

// call to Service Bus SDK API resulted proxy connection failed
```

- I have other node app that successfully communicates to other clouds through a http tunneling with the similar above http options with this same proxy server.

Has anyone successfully got the Azure SDK for node to work with proxy?  Is there any other proxy configuration that I need to specify?

Thx,

Answer (score 1):

Normally, azure node sdk will automatically look up for proxy in the environment variables by using the ProxyFilter. To make it works for me, I set in my code HTTPS_PROXY and HTTP_PROXY variables like this:

```
process.env.HTTPS_PROXY="http://hostname:port"
process.env.HTTP_PROXY="http://hostname:port"
```

Answer (score 0):

As I know, Azure ServiceBus SDK for Node has a filter named `ProxyFilter` that you can see its source code at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/b527caff845a0a4a28eaf08039ad6d5443d5ae54/lib/common/lib/services/filters/proxyfilter.js.

Try to use the `ProxyFilter` to set proxy for ServiceBus client, please see the testing code for `ProxyFilter` at https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-node/blob/b527caff845a0a4a28eaf08039ad6d5443d5ae54/test/common/filters/proxyfilter-tests.js to know how to use it.

Hope it helps. Best Regards.

Comment: I ran the Azure SDK for Node suite test - 'npm test'.  The test had 5 tests failed with the same error I had with the node app.  
`2) servicebusservice-tests storageConnectionStringsEndpointHttpExplicit:
     Uncaught AssertionError: { [Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=Parse Error] code: 'ECONNRESET' } == null
      at `.

Comment: @JamesNW Did you setting the environment variables that be required by the test script?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are using the older `azure-sb` package that relies on the HTTP REST apis. If you instead use the newer `@azure/service-bus` package which uses the faster AMQP implementation, there is a sample at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure/azure-sdk-for-js/service-bus-javascript/ that shows how to set up proxy using web sockets.